# Using palm mojo on web pages?

Tags: webos, palm-pre, palm, mojo

I want to customize my web page for Palm pre. Is the a way to use Mojo in web pages for palm pre? Can I for example use a Mojo picker or a scroll tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [ENYO](http://enyojs.com/) in your HTML on any platform.

> Built from the ground-up for mobile first - Enyo powers webOS, and was
>   designed from the beginning to be fast and work great on mobile
>   devices Now available for desktop and cross-browser development - Enyo
>   2.0 now runs across mobile environments and desktop browsers including Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer Highly customizable and
>   extensible - Enyo core can be expanded with modules, UI widgets, and
>   more Lightweight and fast - Enyo 2.0 core is about 13KB gzipped, and
>   built for fast application rendering and performance Simple,
>   self-contained, and easy to digest - Build increasingly complex
>   functionality starting with simple, reusable components Built to scale
>   - Enyo was created on the principles needed to build vast, complex mobile and web applications Open Source - Enyo is available under the
>   Apache License, Version 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

No, Mojo is an SDK that is executed on the Palm device (e.g. Pre, Pixi). The browser will not interpret (or should not interpret) code that it finds written in webpages. This would be a HUGE security vulnerability.

Comment: I'd be interested to see you make any Mojo call from within a browser and have it interact with the OS or browser; and I would hazard a guess that HP would too 'cause that seems to be a security hole to me.

Comment: Well I understand that Prototype works in the webOS browser but Prototype != Mojo. So I'll agree that prototype calls will work because that has nothing to do with Mojo. However, stand by my earlier statement. I'd like to see a website that used any of the "Widgets":https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/mojo/widgets.html in a website that worked.

Comment: I have an app in the catalog too [PodSnatcher](http://www.precentral.net/podsnatcher). There is no way of building a website that utilizes the Mojo framework or widgets outside webOS; unless you place the mojo framework code somewhere off the devise so that you are capable of including it within the header of the website. What is more, the SDK license does not allow for this: [From unwiredben an HP/Palm Employee](https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12329&p=62458). So you still want to keep arguing your uninformed point? (BTW thanks for the down-vote, classy!)